# Algoritmo não entra no Catch (try/catch)

Tags: php, try-catch

Estou aprendendo programação e me deparei com o try catch, contudo meu código nunca entra no catch..

```
<?php
class NewsLetter{
    public function cadastrarEmail($email){
        if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
            throw new Exception("Este email é invalido",1);
        else:
            echo"ok";
        endif;
    }
}


$Newsletter = new NewsLetter();

try{
    $Newsletter->cadastrarEmail("@haha");
} catch(Expection $e){
    echo"aaaaaaaaaaa";
    echo"Erro: ".$e->getCode();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você escreveu errado Exception

```
catch(Expection $e)
```

o correto seria

```
catch(Exception $e)
```